# Cant deploy Meteor app in Zeit, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, vercel

I try to upload my METEOR project to zeit and I get

> 502  An error occured with your deployment.

then I run now logs and get the following error

> /usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
>                                         throw(ex);

```
 TypeError: Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors is not a function
 at insert (packages/mongo/collection.js:435:12)
 at updateVersions (packages/autoupdate.js:125:20)
 at packages/autoupdate.js:189:3
 at Function.time (/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)
 at /usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:423:13
 at /usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:464:5
 at Function.run (/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
 at /usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:462:11
```

What could be wrong?

- node version v8.9.3
- npm version 5.5.1

Comment: have the same error running with METEOR@1.6.1-beta.18

Comment: what version of mongo package are you using?

Comment: I am using METEOR@1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error traced to commit:
[mongo 1.3.1 changes](http://TypeError:%20Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors%20is%20not%20a%20function%20%20at%20insert%20(packages/mongo/collection.js:435:12)%20%20at%20updateVersions%20(packages/autoupdate.js:125:20)%20%20at%20packages/autoupdate.js:189:3%20%20at%20Function.time%20(/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:309:28)%20%20at%20/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:423:13%20%20at%20/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:464:5%20%20at%20Function.run%20(/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)%20%20at%20/usr/src/app/bundle/programs/server/boot.js:462:11)

See issue created:
[Meteor Issue 9470](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9470)

Comment: should I downgrade to METEOR@1.5 ?